# Lagrangian of Newtonian gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

In this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)#Newtonian_gravity) page we can read:

> The Lagrangian density for Newtonian gravity is:
>
> $$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},t)= - \rho (\mathbf{x},t) \Phi (\mathbf{x},t) - {1 \over 8 \pi G} (\nabla \Phi (\mathbf{x},t))^2,$$

while in this [other wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory#Classical_fields) we can see:

> The simplest classical field is a real scalar field — a real number at
> every point in space that changes in time. It is denoted as $ϕ(x, t)$,
> where $x$ is the position vector, and $t$ is the time. Suppose the
> Lagrangian of the field, $L$, is
>
> $$L = \int d^3x\,\mathcal{L} = \int d^3x\,\left[\frac 12 \dot\phi^2 - \frac 12 (\nabla\phi)^2 - \frac 12 m^2\phi^2\right]. $$

I assume both expressions of Lagrangian density must agree(?). I can define $m=4 \pi G \rho$, but even after that there are two important differences:

1. term in $\dot{\phi}$ not present in first equation.
2. term in $\rho \phi$ of first equation seems to be $m^2 \phi^2$ in second one.

Must these two equations agree? if they must, how to pass from one to the other?

Related: [Lagrangian potential for Newtonian gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571070/) but curiously it talks about an expression not currently found in wiki page.

Comment: Those are two completely different lagrangians, as is stated in their names. Is there a reason you believe they refer to the same object?

Comment: The two Lagrangians have nothing to do with each other, other than both involving (different kinds of) scalar fields.

Answer (score 3):

These actions are logicaly different.

First Lagrangian describe **nonrelativistic scalar field**:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},t)= - \rho (\mathbf{x},t) \Phi (\mathbf{x},t) - {1 \over 8 \pi G} (\nabla \Phi (\mathbf{x},t))^2
$$

Second Lagrangian describe **relativistic scalar field**:
$$
L = \int d^3x\,\mathcal{L} = \int d^3x\,\left[\frac 12 \dot\phi^2 - \frac 12 (\nabla\phi)^2 - \frac 12 m^2\phi^2\right]
$$

First action can be deduced not from second action, but as non-relativistic Newtonian limit of Einstein-Hilbert action coupled to matter if one will use metric in leading order (see for example [David Tong: Lectures on General Relativity](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr.html), section 5.1):

$$
ds^2 = -(1+2\Phi)dt^2 + (1-2\Phi) \, d\mathbf{x} \cdot d\mathbf{x}
 $$

Answer (score 3):

The first Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},t)=
-\rho(\mathbf{x},t)\Phi(\mathbf{x},t)-\frac{1}{8\pi G}(\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{x},t))^2$$
describes the gravity potential $\Phi(\mathbf{x},t)$ (a scalar field)
in the presence of the density $\rho(\mathbf{x},t)$ (another scalar field).

The second Lagrangian density
<sub>(I have added the $(\mathbf{x},t)$ dependencies for more clarity)</sub>
$$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x},t)=
\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi(\mathbf{x},t)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi(\mathbf{x},t))^2 - \frac 12 m^2\phi(\mathbf{x},t)^2$$
describes *a single particle* by a scalar field $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$.
Here $m$ is not a field, but just a constant number (the mass of the single particle).

These are two entirely different phenomena.
Hence there is no reason to expect any similarity between the two.