# Evaluation Lagrangian for gravitational field/ Lagrangian density for gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Given the Lagrangian density for a gravitation potential:
$$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{r},t) = -\rho(\mathbf{r},t)\,\phi(\mathbf{r})-\dfrac{1}{8\,\pi\,G}\,(\nabla\,\phi(\mathbf{r}))^2$$
how to derive the Newtons gravity law out of it?

It is demanded to use the Lagrangian for fields:

$$\sum_{\mu = 0}^3\,\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\,x^{\mu}}}\,\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}-\dfrac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi} = 0$$

I were just introduced to this topic hence I am a little overwhelmed. Just plugging into the equation without giving a thought doesn't seem that intuitive, because I don't know how to deal with the expression $\fbox{$\dfrac{\partial(\nabla\,\phi(\mathbf{r})^2)}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}$}$ for instance. this would require knowing $\phi(\mathbf{r})$ exactly but I'm fairy sure it should be solved without any concrete formula. According to Wiki after doing all the calculation it should collapse to: $$4\,\pi \,G\,\rho(\mathbf{r},t) = \Delta \phi(\mathbf{r},t) $$ but so far this is far in front of me. Any hints are absolutely welcome.

Comment: It's almost always better to express equations like this in index form, i.e. with Einstein summation the Lagrangian reads $L= -\rho\phi - \frac{1}{8\pi G} (\partial_\mu \phi)(\partial_\mu \phi)$ and then it's just a matter of applying the product rule

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571070/2451